# LXML Clarifications... Pretty, but complicated!

Tags: linux, python, html, programming, web

I have only recently met this lib and the first impact was not pleasant at all! First of all, from this site https://lxml.de/ I don't know about you, but I didn't understand anything! Too complicated and messed up ... talk like you already know things when I'm actually learning! The wrapped examples are difficult to understand and on some points there is a very superficial description. For this I ask you two things:

**first:**

If you know a site with good documentation tell me and I will be grateful.

**Second:**

My main purpose is to parse only **HTML** (and not **XML**) sources. In that tutorial (and many people too) I see that they use both **etree** (`lxml.etree`) and **html** (`lxml.html`) methods ... what changes between the two? Because I still don't understand it ...

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: `talk like you already know things when I'm actually learning!`. Obviously it refers to the lxml topic in question ... I have read many other documents regarding various libraries for python and have never had any difficulties. In this case, however, the thing is different. it is not certain that you understand one thing and consequently it also applies to others!

Comment: this example may help ... https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html

Comment: Thanks...but i still don't understand the difference between `etree` and `html`. What is the difference between the two? Why do people use both or just one of the two?

Comment: maybe because of the differences betwesn XML and HTML ... XML has a stricter structure ... HTML is kind of lax

Comment: like, reading the first part of the tutorial we can find this sentence: "_If your code only uses the ElementTree API and does not rely on any functionality that is specific to lxml.etree, you can also use (any part of) the following import chain as a fall-back to the original ElementTree_"... but, what is ElementTree!?! Maah...only he understands. And that's the way it is for most things. I really don't like this source ... I hope someone can point me to a more detailed one!

Comment: Also, one thing I noticed (correct me if I'm wrong) is that in lxml the data you enter to analyze an **html** document (for example with xpath), must effectively correspond to the paths that are in the document and therefore you must know them. ... and if I want to webscraping a site that I don't know (and therefore I don't know any xpath of the document) how can I do it with this library? For example, I still don't understand if it is possible to search only for certain TAGs (tpo: 'div', 'a', 'span', etc ..), or you just have to go to xpath

Comment: If some documentation refers to something you don't know yet, then research it.  e.g. copy-paste "ElementTree API" into a search engine, or hunt for information on that topic in related documentation or the same website.   Yes, that can be frustrating when you're learning something complex and new to you, and sometimes (often) docs could be written or structured better or have more links to related docs, but the world isn't perfect. being able to deal with that fact is an essential skill for learning.

Comment: ranting about it here isn't going to help.  Post a specific question (without the rant) or search for an alternative that does roughly the same thing but is easier to learn. These are some of the more useful things you could do instead of posting a rant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse HTML with Python, use [BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) instead. HTML is not a decently behaved format, and using an XML parser is unlikely to work.